# Node.js: Synchronous child_process spawn

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, child-process, synchronous, spawn

Looking for the easiest way to synchronously spawn a `child_process`.

Sort of surprised I can't find anything.

I don't have a lot of experience with promises, async/await so I don't really have any existing code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the synchronous spawn counterpart here:

https://nodejs.org/docs/v5.0.0/api/child_process.html#child_process_synchronous_process_creation